# the position of the avplayer in a containerView is not what it should be T_T

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I'm working on the Avplayer . I've got a containerView for the Avplayer and i set the frame of the Avplayer like this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 400);
playerLayer.frame=frame;
[containerView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
```

But the Avplayer is not at the posiotion it should be T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve it by myself,instead of using the frame i use the [playerview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW11)

with the playerview ,u can use the storyboard to make the position of the avplayer,and also the size of it.